# Is it possible to locate places of a specific type (ie. hospitals) and provide driving directions to them from my Android application?

Tags: android, google-maps, driving-directions

I would like to determine which of a specific type of location (ie. which hospital) is closest to the device's current location and then provide the user with driving directions to that location (ie. the closest hospital).  I have heard about a Google Maps API that I believe will help me with this task.  (I have already obtained the user's location by using the device's GPS.)

From reading a little about the Google Maps API, I've learned that it provides UI elements used to control maps.  I'm wondering if I can use it to search for specific locations (such as hospitals) and if I can receive turn-by-turn directions from it (as coming up with the directions myself would be a headache).

Does anyone know what functionality the Google Maps API provides?

Comment: Have you done any research into it yourself yet?  Perhaps you can provide us with specific questions you have about different parts of the maps external library: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/

Comment: Do you want to make an Android application (with a couple of possible options at least) or a use Javascript Google Maps API within a webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like something you'd want to perhaps use the Google Places API for:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

However, note that there are many locations for which the Places API does not currently return a whole lot of results.  See, for example, [Google Map V3.0 Places Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057938/google-map-v3-0-places-api).

Comment: Thanks, that seems to solve the problem of locating hospitals.  I've found the [Google Directions API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/) for the second half of my request.